# react grid - calling a function for rendering a cell

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-data-table-component` as a grid component in react.
I have set up a columns array such as this:

```
  this.columns = [
        {
            name: 'Id',
            selector: 'FileId',
            sortable: true,
            left: true,
            width: "80px",
            cell: function (row) {
                return <div title={row.FileName}>{row.FileName}</div>;
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Info',
            selector: 'FileId',
            sortable: false,
            left: true,
            width: "80px"
        },
```

And now when I want to add a custom renderer such as this in o

```
 {
          name: 'File Name',
          selector: 'FileName',
          sortable: true,
          left: true,
          width: "250px",
          cell: function (row) {
               this.calculateWarnings(row);                    
            }
        },
```

I get an error related to scope.

I did add to the constructor:

```
this.calculateWarnings = this.calculateWarnings.bind(this);
```

What am I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```js
cell: function (row) {
```

with this

```js
cell: (row) => {
```